# Change language of target platform in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How can I change the language of the Eclipse Application that I start from within eclipse? (for example to german)

I tried to add `-nl de` to program arguments in the run configurations, and `-Duser.language=de` in VM arguments, but none of that worked...

I am using Mars and the targt platform is Helios. Barbel language package is installed in Mars, and starting eclipse itself in German works just fine.

Comment: I think you have to write '-Duser.language=de_DE'

Comment: I've tried that too...

Answer (score 1):

"-nl de" in program arguments should be the correct way to do it.

Please check that the fragment bundles are available and checked in the plug-ins tab of the launch configuration.

Do you have Babel installed in your Target Platform? if I understand well what you said, it is installed in your Eclipse Mars installation but no tin the Helios Target Platform. if it is the case, it is the reason why you don't have access to babel plugins.

regards,